# How to select data from a combobox with an object as values using a String in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a ComboBox in javafx that uses the Degree object as its values. On the other hand, I have a TableView with Thesis object as it's values, that has a listener that returns a string of the degreeName when that row is clicked. How can I use that 'degreeName' I retrieved from the table as a means to select the value from the ComboBox with the same degreeName?

I use Degree Object as the values in my ComboBox because I want to retrieve all attributes from that value when I use it on my program.

So far, I have already generated the ComboBox with this code:

```
private void set_degreeCombo() throws SQLException
{
    ObservableList<Degree> degreeList = DegreeDAO.init_degreeData();

    thesisDegreeCB.setCellFactory(
            (cb) -> new ListCell<Degree>(){
                @Override
                protected void updateItem(Degree item, boolean empty)
                {
                    super.updateItem(item, empty);

                    if(item == null || empty)
                        setText(null);
                    else
                        setText(item.getDegree());
                }
            }
    );

    thesisDegreeCB.setConverter(
            new StringConverter<Degree>() {
                @Override
                public String toString(Degree degree) {
                    return (degree == null) ? null : degree.getDegree();
                }

                @Override
                public Degree fromString(String degreeString) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
    );

    thesisDegreeCB.setItems(degreeList);
    thesisDegreeCB.getSelectionModel().select(0);
}
```

And I have a listener in my TableView:

```
thesisIDCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().idProperty().asObject());
    thesisTitleCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().titleProperty());
    thesisYearCol.setCellValueFactory(data -> data.getValue().yearProperty());

    thesisTbl.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
            (observable, oldVal, newVal) ->
            {
                if(newVal != null)
                {
                    if(newVal.getId() != 0)
                    {
                        thesis = newVal;
                        try {
                            generateThesisData();
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Adding New Data.");
                        clearThesisData();
                    }
                } else
                    clearThesisData();
            }
    );
```

What I want to happen is when I call generateThesisData(), I want to select the ComboBox with the same degreeName as the degreeName in my table.

So far I only use this code:

```
thesisDegreeCB.getSelectionModel().select(thesis.getDegreeID() - 1);
```

and get it's index value, which is not reliable because I have an option to delete a data from the degree table.

I hope anybody can help me with this one. Thank you very much and have a great day.

Comment: [mcve] please ...

Comment: Do you have `thesis.getDegree`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `Degree` implements `equals` in a way that yields `true` when used for the combination of the data from the `TableView` and one of the items in the `ComboBox`, there's no issue. Simply pass the item to select.

*(BTW: Using `ComboBox.setValue` is a bit more concise than using the selection model. I prefer setting the value this way.)*

```
thesisDegreeCB.setValue(theDegreeFromTableViewItem);
```

Otherwise you need to find a matching item among the combobox items(assuming they are already initialized):

```
thesisDegreeCB.setValue(thesisDegreeCB.getItems().stream()
                            .filter(degree -> theDegreeFromTableViewItem.getDegree().equals(degree.getDegree()))
                            .findFirst().orElse(null));
```